# I want to disable the options when once selected - laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am creating dynamic Dropdown list where the options are coming from database.
When once selected a option it should get disable in next selection and should get enable when selection removed.

Here is my select tag which is a laravel code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="category">Category</label>
{{
     Form::select('category',(isset($data) && isset($data['kra_category'])) ? $data['kra_category'] : [],
     htmlSelect('category',$data),
     array('name'=>'kra[0][category]', 'data-name' => 'category', 'class' => 'form-control chosen-select kra_category', 'placeholder' => '', 'data-placeholder' => 'Select Category'))
}}
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery function...
The function is yet to be created.

```
$('.chosen-select').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. You mention a "next selection" but I don't know what you mean by that. There's only a single select in the code you shared.

Comment: select are generated dynamically once add button is clicked. but what i want is once a option is selected in select1 then it should not be appear in select2

Comment: @apokryfos please give me answer

Comment: How are they generated dynamically?  Again I only see a single select here. I need a more concrete example.

Comment: There is a add button which add same form. In my new form there is same select tag like previous but i dont want the value which is being selected in previous form.. @apokryfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this function..

```
 $(".chosen-select").change(function(){          
       var value = $(".chosen-select option:selected").val();
       var theDiv = $(".is" + value);
       $(".chosen-select option:selected").hide().siblings().removeProp('disabled');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#test').change(function () {
  var indexOfSelect = $(this).find('option:selected');
  $(this).find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
  //indexOfSelect.attr('disabled','disabled');
  indexOfSelect.prop('disabled', 'false');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>AA</option>
<option>BB</option>
<option>CC</option>
<option>DD</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use .prop() and .removeAttr();